# How do I export from a module without the src directory?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, ecmascript-6

I have two modules. One is a dependency of the other.

One module, `base-module` is structured like -

```
/
    /src
        /Widget
            index.tsx
package.json
```

and I want to import `Widget` into the other module.

I have added `base-module` as a dependency in its `package.json`.

It works if I write

`import Widget from "base-module/src/Widget"`

How do I get it to be

`import Widget from "base-module/Widget"` ?

I am using webpack and typescript.

Comment: They are in separate modules. I will update the question to make that more clear.

Comment: Use alias in webpack https://webpack.js.org/configuration/resolve/

Comment: What does the `package.json` say about the entry point to the module?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define `index.tsx` in `base-module/` and import, export `Widget` there.